# Read CSV/Excel file which contains some Dutch or French characters in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to import the CSV/Excel file in Mysql database using PHP which is in following format.

```
+---------+------------+------------+----------------------+
| Sex     | First Name | Last Name  | Address              |
+---------+------------+------------+----------------------+
| Male    | John       | Mice       | special Charachters  |
| Female  | Ana        | Johnson    | special Charachters  |
+---------+------------+------------+----------------------+
```

I have readed it successfully using core PHP but it contains some French characters in address field and I'm unable

to read that French characters if anybody  help me to sort this then it will be great help to me.

Here is my code

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("Geneva.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c]. "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: What means 'unable to read'? You `echo` the string and is not the own that you read or you are storing the string in MySQL and it is not stored as you expect. Also please add some code on how you read the file and store the data to MySQL

Comment: Hello sir , below is the my code $row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("Geneva.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
           echo $data[$c]. "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}  and its showing like Fran�ais

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert problematic string (or even all of them) to UTF-8:

```
$address = mb_convert_encoding($address_in_french, "UTF-8");
```

This will convert any given string to UTF-8 character encoding. For more info, check this out:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php